# Auto Read SMS in web app

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, web

Is there any way in which a web app can read incoming SMS to automate OTP verification. I know this is possible for native android apps. But is it possible if I want to do it through website?

Answer (score 0):

You have use a phonegap plugin that can read sms events just like we do in native apps. You can build your own or use this https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms